# Is there a way to automate clicking on the display matches icons in flashscore

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver

https://www.flashscore.com/ recently changed their platform so I have to manually select 'display matches' ribbon on the cream ribbon with an arrow icon, on lesser known leagues on their main page. I therefore wanted to automate this process. I have tried accessing their view page source but the display matches links are not embedded in html link tags. I thought it might be embedded in JS code as images since when right-clicking on the display matches icon, google displays a "search image" option on the hover menu.

I am not good in JS or web crawling so I got stuck. I dont know if it's possible, but I thought maybe they have hidden the links to images or maybe they are in the .js extensions that can be found in the head tag. Search for this using CTR+F to get the .js files, `<script defer src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js" type="text/javascrip">`. Then start scrolling to the right.

I tried looking for the links on html reference tags to no avail. As mentioned earlier, they have references to JS code that may have the answer but I'm not proficient in JS.